# MongoDB schema design. Another collection or subdocument?

Tags: mongodb

I cannot find the best way to design the schema of a MongoDB-based app.

I have Places and Users. Users can checkin in those places. I want to save timestamp too. Should I create a separate collection with this structure?

```
{
    _user: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    _place: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Place},
    timestamp: Date
}
```

I've written this as if I was using pseudo-mongoose. Hope it's clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seperate collection you built is totally fine.

If you want to query all places by a user, you should *index* the _user field.

If you want to query all places A by user B you should build a *composed index* over the _user and _place fields.